# Are these elephant ears ready for uppotting?

Tags: repotting

These Colocasia esculenta are in an approx 7 inch diameter pot (from the top). Should I uppot them? If so, should I uppot separately or together? And would 12~15 inch ones work for these separately?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My experience with elephant ears is that you can't kill them. As I pull them up from around my pond in all sizes , I have used them as mulch and also discarded them in the adjacent woods as organic matter . There are now many dozens of elephant ears growing in the area ( US garden zone 8). I have had some half the size of yours and twice that size , they all grow.

Comment: "discarded in adjacent woods as organic matter" ... Do you own those woods? If not, what you're doing is called illegal dumping. I used to work for a forested nature preserve and we had a huge problem with this. People would just chuck their dead shrubs and lawn clippings into the woods. It's unsightly, doesn't provide any benefit to the woods, can actually harm the plants underneath, and can spread invasive species.